# Check health of main container using a sidecar in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

Is there a generic way to query a container's health?

I want to inject a generic sidecar container into every pod which exposes the 'main' container's health on a different endpoint.

My main container is protected behind `oauth2` so I cannot do any uptime checks using `StatusCake` for example.

The idea was to inject a sidecar which can report only the container health on an exposed path. Then I could configure `StatusCake` to query that endpoint instead.

I could query the 'official' health endpoint in my sidecar, but I don't know how to inject the path generically.

Also I was wondering whether I could check the health via some `kubectl` command?

Comment: there's nothing wrong in exposing the health(z) endpoint of your container without oauth2

Comment: True, actually I forgot that. I was hoping I didn't need to touch all the Ingress and instead just inject sidecars.

Comment: Ah, and some Ingress come from charts I have no control over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically can't do what you're wanting to, and I'll explain why: if you register a health check with Kubernetes and it returns not ready, your service won't route requests to it. Which means that if you're not ready, nothing exposed over HTTP is going to work.

There is a way around it, though: write a service that proxies to all the other pods' endpoints.

For reference, this is what Kubernetes *intends* you to do

- Create live and ready probes for your pod.
- These should be *unauthenticated* and typically provide basically no information other than healthy/not healthy.
- Once you register these probes with Kubernetes, the last success/failure will be viewable using kubectl.
- If you really don't want people viewing them, don't expose that url to the outside world.
- You can always provide an alternative that provides detailed information. This *could* require authentication.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using [readiness probe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/) provided by kubernetes as health check of the sidecar container.Then you can use `kubectl` to check the health of the sidecar container as well as use StatusCake

As part of the implementation of the readiness probe of the sidecar you do a health check of the main container. Since the sidecar container and main container are part of same pod `localhost` can be used to connect to main container from the sidecar container.

Comment: I don't understand how this would solve my problem. I want to be able to ping the health of my pod from outside the cluster without providing any credentials and without compromising the security of my cluster. `kubectl` is only possible with credentials.

Comment: kubectl is not possible without credentials..but in this caae you don't need to use kubectl..you can hit the unprotected endpoint of the sidecar  from outside the cluster via curl or anything..when you hit the unprotected endpoint of sidecar it will hit the protected endpoint of main container. the readiness probe helps in monitoring and restarting of the containers in case of failure

Comment: When health check of sidecar fails, k restarts the container not the pod. I supposed one can catch the signterm in the sidecar then do a kill of the main-container.